# how to send multiple sms to one recepient only on a button click?

Tags: android, sms

I need to create an application wherein on a single button click i want to send multiple SMS to a particular number and then capture the delivery reports and store it in the database and show it in my app in a listview. The messages to be sent are physically not typed by the user instead it comes from the database.

How do i acheive this functionality?? Please help!

Thanks in Advance!

Comment: what you have tried so far?

Comment: @Shayanpourvatan i have used SmsManager in a for loop to send sms. The smses are going but issue comes with the delivery reports. For example if i send 10 sms at once i get like 7-8 reports back which defeats the purpose of the app.

Comment: please post your code, maybe some sms not delivered.